# Angular 5 prevent app ready until service has loaded configuration file

Tags: angular

Is there an Anguarly way of preventing the app from officially loading until a service has loaded a json file? I host a config.json file that stores all the endpoint paths and some metadata that hasn't finished loading before some services start to request it.

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

  private Configuration: Configuration;

  constructor(private Web: Http)
  {
    this.LoadConfig();
  }

  public GetConfig(): Configuration
  { 
    var b = this.Configuration;
    return this.Configuration;
  }

  public Loaded(): boolean
  { 
    return this.Configuration != null;
  }

  private LoadConfig(): void
  {
    var getConfig = this.Web.get('/assets/config.json').map(res => res.json() as Configuration).subscribe(data =>
    {
      this.Configuration = data;
    });
  }

}
```

I tried doing this in the main App.module.ts to try and give it as much time as possible but still it doesn't load that file before other services begin requesting it.

```
export class AppModule
{
  constructor(private ConfigLoader: ConfigurationService)
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following in you app.module.ts

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

export function startupAppConfigs(appConfigs: ConfigurationService): Function {
    return () => appConfigs.LoadConfig();
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [ {
        // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: startupAppConfigs,
        deps: [ConfigurationService],
        multi: true
    }
    .....
```

Note: Make the LoadConfig() method return promise. Refer code snippet below:

```
public LoadConfig()
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      this.Web.get('/assets/config.json')
      .map(res => res.json() as Configuration)
      .subscribe(data =>
      {
        this.Configuration = data;
        resolve(true);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am getting error: No provider for ConfigurationService!

Comment: Alright I am not getting any errors but nothing loads just a white page

Comment: @BaileyMiller, please refer the updated LoadConfig() method.